# Admin and Staff can not login at a time on same domain but different URLs

Tags: java, session, servlets, session-state, http-status-code-500

Java Servlet

There totally two separate modules i.e. `Staff` and `Admin`
Here is how they have URLs

1. http://127.0.0.1:8080/adminLogin
2. http://127.0.0.1:8080/staffLogin

When I login as Staff and try to login as Admin using same browser then its throwing the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
    package.staff.credentials.session.StaffSession.isStaff(StaffSession.java:57)
    package.staff.credentials.session.StaffSession.isStaffSession(StaffSession.java:36)
    package.staff.site.Template.navbar(Template.java:55)
    package.staff.site.Template.body(Template.java:37)
    package.staff.site.Template.webPage(Template.java:14)
    package.staff.credentials.login.Login.doGet(Login.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

**Update**
Here is code:

```
    private static boolean isStaff(HttpServletRequest request) {
        boolean staffSession = false;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        int userType = (Integer) session.getAttribute(SessionProperty.userType());
        int valueAsStaff = Integer.parseInt(SessionProperty.userValueAsStaff());
        
        if (userType == valueAsStaff) {
            staffSession = true;
        } else {
            staffSession = false;
        }
    return staffSession;
    }

    private static boolean isSessionValid(HttpServletRequest request) {
        boolean isSessionValid = false;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session == null) {
            isSessionValid = false;
        } else {
            isSessionValid = true;
        }
        return isSessionValid;
    }

    public static boolean isStaffSession(HttpServletRequest request) {
        boolean session = false; 
        if(isSessionValid(request)) {
            if(isStaff(request)) {
                session = true;
            }
        }
    return session;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please update your post and provide the code for your methods `isStaff` and `isStaffSession`?

Comment: @ThisIsntSparta. I have update my question and provided the code

Comment: @BalusC can you please help me?

Comment: Your Exception says that something is `null` in your `isStaff()` method, and I am guessing, that something happens on the two lines where you initialize the two variables `userType` and `valueAsStaff`. Check those out and see what is exactly `null`.

Comment: When I logout admin then everything is working fine. Is there the problem that attributes in both modules are same but their value is different? May I keep different names for attributes?